# Checking "PropertyNotSetInConstructor" on a custom function with Psalm

Tags: php, psalm-php

Is there a way I could tell [Psalm](https://psalm.dev/) to check other functions than `__construct()` methods for ensuring all properties are set when a class is instantiated ?

In some PHP library, Psalm complains about `PropertyNotSetInConstructor` because it is not able to infer the whole work that is done in each constructor. The constructors all rely on calling dynamically the right function using `call_user_func_array()`. I am not suprised Psalm cannot see that but I need a workaround to show it the right function to analyze as a constructor.

The underlying reason is that we mimic constructors with different number of arguments so we can write both `$x = new X()` and `$x = new X($a, $b)`.